# R markdown doesn't find object

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am using R markdown to knitter my codes into a word document

I am pretty new to R as well as to R markdown 
I have the following code :

```
{r, eval=TRUE, fig.height=7, fig.width=5, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
lifeExpectancy <- rename(lifeExpectancy, Incomegroup= WORLDBANKINCOMEGROUP)
plife <- ggplot(lifeExpectancy, aes(x= LifeExpectancy))
plife1 <- plife + geom_histogram(fill="white", aes(color= Incomegroup))
plife1 <- plife1 +facet_grid(SEX~Incomegroup) + xlab("average life
expectancy")
plife1
```

this is the warning message it returns :

```
Quitting from lines 32-38 (Termpaper_Franziska.Rmd) 
error in rename_(.data, .dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) : 
Object 'lifeExpectancy' not found
calls : <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval 
> rename -> rename_
stopped`
```

What I already did :

I set the working directory correctly for R markdown as well as for my original script

I used

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir =
"C:/Users/Maxi/Desktop/PrettyPlots2016/Termpaper")
```

to set the working directory but that didn't help either.

Last but not least I also set

`eval=FALSE`

but then I didn't get my plot of course, which didn't help me either.

If anyone has a solution for my dilemma I would be very happy to hear it !

Thank you a lot !

Comment: It looks like `lifeExpectancy` isn't being loaded into an environment. Is it in a package? A csv, an RData file? Do you need to include a `data`, `read csv`, or `load` call somewhere?

Comment: I loaded `lifeExpectancy` to my global environment as a normal txt. file. I tried to run  the `load` call previously to the `rename` command in the chunk . This way or the other without  calling `load` it ran perfectly well, only the knittering failed and still does.

Comment: it seems you have an object `lifeExpectancy` in the global environment of your rsession process, but you should remember, that Rstudio starts a new separate rsession process when kinitting .rmd file, and that new process will have an empty global environment (well, almost empty). To pass your objects from working rsession to the knitting rsession, you may, for example, send `save.image()` command to the console, and insert `load(".RData")` as the first line of rscript-chunk in your .rmd document

Comment: That solved my problem ! Thank you a lot !